# Bottom Overflowed by pixels Cant Fix

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, overflow

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

import '../appbar.dart';

class DetailProductHeading extends StatelessWidget {
  const DetailProductHeading({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppBar(title: 'Detail Product'),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(35.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xFFFAFAFA),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0)),
              ),
              child: InkWell(
                child: Center(
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'image/headphone.png',
                    height: 300,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 25,
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 300,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'TMA-2HD Wireless',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: GoogleFonts.dmSans().fontFamily,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      fontSize: 25,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Rp. 1.500.000",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: GoogleFonts.dmSans().fontFamily,
                      color: Color(0xFFFE3A30),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          Icon(
                            Icons.star,
                            color: Colors.yellow,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 5.0,
                          ),
                          Text('4.0')
                        ],
                      ),
                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5)),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            '86 Reviews',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: GoogleFonts.dmSans().fontFamily,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 60,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 107,
                            height: 20,
                            child: OutlinedButton(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                                backgroundColor: Color(0xFFE5F6DF),
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: Text(
                                "Tersedia: 250",
                                style: (TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: GoogleFonts.dmSans().fontFamily,
                                  fontSize: 12,
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                )),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 15,
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    thickness: 0.50,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 15,
                  ),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Description Product',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: GoogleFonts.dmSans().fontFamily,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 18,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'The speaker unit contains a diaphragm that is precision-grown from NAC 
                         Audio bio-cellulose, making it stiffer, lighter and stronger than regular 
                         PET speaker units, and allowing the sound-producing diaphragm to vibrate 
                         without the levels of distortion found in other speakers.',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: GoogleFonts.dmSans().fontFamily,
                          fontSize: 12,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 8,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'The speaker unit contains a diaphragm that is precision-grown from NAC 
                         Audio bio-cellulose, making it stiffer, lighter and stronger than regular 
                         PET speaker units, and allowing the sound-producing diaphragm to vibrate 
                         without the levels of distortion found in other speakers.',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: GoogleFonts.dmSans().fontFamily,
                          fontSize: 12,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `body:Padding` with `SingleChildScrollView` for now.

```dart
class DetailProductHeading extends StatelessWidget {
  const DetailProductHeading({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(35.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xFFFAFAFA),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0)),
                ),
                child: InkWell(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'image/headphone.png',
                      height: 300,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 25,
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 300,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'TMA-2HD Wireless',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: GoogleFonts.dmSans().fontFamily,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        fontSize: 25,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Rp. 1.500.000",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: GoogleFonts.dmSans().fontFamily,
                        color: Color(0xFFFE3A30),
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 5,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.star,
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 5.0,
                            ),
                            Text('4.0')
                          ],
                        ),
                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5)),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              '86 Reviews',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: GoogleFonts.dmSans().fontFamily,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 60,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 107,
                              height: 20,
                              child: OutlinedButton(
                                onPressed: () {},
                                style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                                  backgroundColor: Color(0xFFE5F6DF),
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                child: Text(
                                  "Tersedia: 250",
                                  style: (TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: GoogleFonts.dmSans().fontFamily,
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                    color: Colors.green,
                                  )),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    Divider(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      thickness: 0.50,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Description Product',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: GoogleFonts.dmSans().fontFamily,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 18,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 8,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '''The speaker unit contains a diaphragm that is precision-grown from NAC 
                           Audio bio-cellulose, making it stiffer, lighter and stronger than regular 
                           PET speaker units, and allowing the sound-producing diaphragm to vibrate 
                           without the levels of distortion found in other speakers.''',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: GoogleFonts.dmSans().fontFamily,
                            fontSize: 12,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wraped my padding with SingleChildScrollView, the error still there. No changes

Comment: There was also issue on text , try to run my snippet